# Why does find_all fail to find a `div` element that is clearly there?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to find the text associated to a `div` element from a webpage parsed with beautifulsoup.

```
print(searchResult)

<div id="results-from-CIDR"><a href="javascript:prefixContribsToggleAll();" id="prefixcontribs-tog">toggle all</a><span id="prefixcontribs-prog">Searching.</span> No changes were found for this wildcard/CIDR range.</div>

print(type(searchResult))

<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>

print(searchResult.find_all("div"))

[]

print(searchResult.find_all("div", attrs={"id":"results-from-CIDR"}))

[]
```

There is clearly a div there. Why doesn't it find it?

Comment: Sometimes, people learning a programming language read questions to learn more about their target language via a somewhat different process. Occasionally, these people can figure out answers to questions because they come from a different perspective. But for this to work, you need a [MCVE]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are just looking for the plain/visible text of the div, without any of the markup, you can access this text through the `searchResult.text` attribute.

The `Tag.find_all()` method only searches for ***descendants*** of `Tag` whose `name` matches the given argument. So in your case, it is returning an empty list because there are no descendant `<divs>`. The only descendants of the example `Tag` that you shared are an `<a>` tag, a `<span>`, and several instances of `NavigableString` (the `bs4` object used to represent visible text in the DOM tree).  If you wanted to use `find_all()` to return the `<div>` in your example, you'd have to call it from the parent `Tag` (or rather, from any element that the target `<div>` is a descendant of).

For instance, if you do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
soup = Soup('<html><body><div id="results-from-CIDR"><a href="javascript:prefixContribsToggleAll();" id="prefixcontribs-tog">toggle all</a><span id="prefixcontribs-prog">Searching.</span> No changes were found for this wildcard/CIDR range.</div></body></html>')
soup.findall('div')
```

... then the element *will* be returned, because it is a descendant of `soup` (the html docroot).

But again, if you're just trying to extract the text, use the `.text` attribute, which gives the visible text for a given tag, and any of its descendants.

Comment: With text like `<li>2018-07-10 <a href="/w/index.php?title=Evan_Vucci&amp;curid=1751380">Evan Vucci</a> (removed false information)</li>`, can I extract the text just before the `a` element?

Comment: If you wanted to get all of the text that is contained within the `<li>` but not the text in the descendants, you could use: `listitem_text = li.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)` where `li` is the `bs4.Tag` object representing the target `<li>`. This will return a list of strings contained in the `<li>`. If you just want the date before the `<a>` tag, you would then do `listitem_text[0]` to retrieve the first string only (which is the date).

Comment: ^ I want to note that this might seem strange, since I just said that `find_all()` only searches descendants, and it seems like I'm using it here to search within the Tag itself. However, in this case, `text=True` tells it to search for instances of `NavigableString` (which is the class that BeautifulSoup uses to represent all plaintext strings inside of HTML documents) within the element too, and these strings technically are children of the `<li>` element.

Comment: @J.Taylor - I know SO policy is to discourage using comments for saying "thank you", but your answer explained something that's been bothering me for ages - so: Thank You! But (there's always a but..), in your comment above you say "these strings technically are children of the  the `<li>` element" - what? why? How is that possible? Is BS misusing the plain meaning of the word "descendants" or am I missing some basic concept?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was kind of mixing contexts there, so it wasn't clear. What I meant is that from the perspective of BS4 (not HTML/DOM standards), the `NavigableString` is considered a child of the `bs4.Tag`. I'm actually not sure how the HTML5 standard defines the relation between tags and the strings inside of them (although I plan to head off now and read about it!)